# Failed to use InsertCursor to add point features

Tags: python, arcpy

I have following python script to create a feature class in an SDE database and try to add point features to it.

```
sde_conn = "d:/sde.sde"
st_fc = arcpy.CreateFeatureclass_management(sde_conn, "LIVE_ST", "POINT","","DISABLED","DISABLED",arcpy.SpatialReference(4326))
rowInserter = arcpy.da.InsertCursor(st_fc, ("SHAPE@X", "SHAPE@Y"))

# FOR loop starts here
    lon = {a number}
    lat = {another number}
    rowInserter.insertRow(([lon, lat]))
# FOR loop ends here

del rowInserter
```

When I ran the script, I received the following error:

```
rowInserter.insertRow(([lon, lat]))
TypeError: expect single [X,Y[,Z[,M]]]
```

Are you able to point me to the right direction to get it fixed? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Got it fixed.
It was my fault that I forgot the lon and lat were string type. To fixed it, I had to convert string type to double.

Comment: I was just going to say that.